# Attach vCard to Email Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments

I am attempting to attach a vCard (*.vcf) to an email intent like so:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Shared Contact via the Foo App");

// vcfFile is a *.vcf file on local storage
Uri vCardUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.foo.fileprovider", vcfFile);
emailIntent.setData(vCardUri);
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

However, the app dies with the following exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO dat=content://com.foo.fileprovider/external_files/Android/data/com.foo/files/generated.vcf (has extras) }
```

I have also tried to explicitly set the type like this:

```
emailIntent.setDataAndType(vCardUri, "text/x-vcard");
```

However, it also blows up with a:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO dat=content://com.foo.fileprovider/external_files/Android/data/com.foo/files/generated.vcf typ=text/x-vcard (has extras) }
```

Is there a way to attach a vCard to an email intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing files is only documented to work with `ACTION_SEND`. Put the `Uri` into `EXTRA_STREAM`. (This **might** also work with `ACTION_SENDTO` with some email apps).

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Shared Contact via the Foo App");

// vcfFile is a *.vcf file on local storage
Uri vCardUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.foo.fileprovider", vcfFile);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, vCardUri);
emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
emailIntent.setType("text/x-vcard");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, null));
```